# Best way to cancel task with functions that don't implement InterruptedException

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I would like to cancel the following task

```
fooFuture = executor.submit(() ->  {
    bar1();
    bar2();
    bar3();
});
```

The bar functions don't implement `InterruptedException`.

Is there a way I can catch an interrupt without checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterruped();` after every instruction?

Comment: In a word, no.  You don’t have to check after *every* line, of course, but methods which can take a long time to execute are responsible for properly handling interrupts.  If they don’t, you’re out of luck, unfortunately.

Comment: @VGR thank you. Could you make this an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. You don’t have to check after *every* line, of course, but methods which can take a long time to execute are responsible for properly handling interrupts. If they don’t, you’re out of luck, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there's no way in Java to just kill off a thread  if during execution not implemented  InterruptedException . If the thread is executing, it just sets a flag and it's up to the thread to notice it. if the thread is waiting or sleeping, it will throw an InterruptedException.

kill the process in which the thread is running. (E.g., call System.exit(int).)

Comment: Thank you. That's what I did. I set a flag